# What is the difference between pluripotent and totipotent cells?

Tags: stem-cells

Both develop into specialized cells.Then how are they different?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_potency. By the way, it is *pluripotent*.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado You can easily correct such spelling mistakes. That's why we have the edit function. And it is not seen as offensive here, as it helps to improve the question/answer.

Answer (score 2):

Expending on Gerando Furtado link

Totipotent cells can differentiate into three germ layers (endoderm, mesoderm, or ectoderm), into cells of the cytotrophoblast layer or syncytiotrophoblast layer of the placenta.

Pluripotent cells can differentiate into the three germ layers (endoderm, mesoderm, or ectoderm).

So totipotent cells develop into the all the cells of the embryonic body and fetal side of the placenta. While pluripotent cells can only develop into cells of the embryonic body.